# Proving a particular inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I want to derive under what conditions the following is positive: **for $x,y,z>0$, when is the following positive?**
$$\frac{1}{3} \ln \left( \frac{x}{y} \right) - \frac{2}{3} \ln \left( \frac{\frac{z}{y} + 1}{\frac{z}{x} + 1} \right) > 0$$

I have some intuitive guess that this is positive if both $|x-1| > |y-1|$ and $|x-1| > |z-1|$, but this is entirely an intuitive guess that I'm unable to show.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated!

Comment: $\frac{x}{y} \left(\frac{\frac{z}{x}+1}{\frac{z}{y}+1}\right)^2 > 1$. $\frac{(z+x)^2}{(z+y)^2} > \frac{x}{y}$. $(z+x)^2 y > (z+y)^2 x$. $(z^2-xy)(y-x) > 0$. $y>x \land z^2 > xy$ or $y < x \land z^2 < xy$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure if there's a way I should mark your comment as the answer.

Comment: No way, because it was comment not answer.